# Firestore/Javascript: How to get a document that is named as a date?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How do I `.()get` a `document` in firestore that is named as a date? Specifically how do I get a latest date named `document` including the `fields` stored in it, in firestore using javascript?

**Image to support my question:**
[image: This is the .get() query I am aiming to accomplish]

**Here is the current code I'm using:**

```
                            firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
                                if(user){
                                    this.userId = user.uid;
                                }
                            let userRef1 = firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(userId).collection("fitbit_sleep");
                            return userRef1.get()
                            .then(function(querySnapshot) {
                                querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
                                    console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
                                    });
                                });
```

**EDIT**

Though my image is only for a specific user. What I am trying to accomplish is to get a "dynamic" query meaning a query that is situable for any user who logs in my system.

For example: if user A has a latest fitbit document named Dec 9, 2019 and user B has a latest fitbit document named Dec 11, 2019.

A single query should be able to determine and get the latest date that the current logged in user has.

Comment: I will suggest not using localized formatted dates as the IDs for documents.  I think you will only run into difficulties with that going forward.  Consider instead using a more predictable format, such as "YYYYMMDD", and format the date on the client in the locale they prefer.  For querying ranges, you should have a field in the document with the data you want to query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IDs of your documents in the `fitbit_sleep` collection are you date strings (i.e. `Dec 9, 2019`). So you just have to pass this string to the [`doc()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference?authuser=1#doc) method, as follows:

```
let userRef1 = firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(userId).collection("fitbit_sleep");

userRef1
  .doc("Dec 9, 2019")
  .get()
  .then(snap => {
      console.log(snap.data());
  });
```

---

Note however that while your document IDs are technically valid (See https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#collections_documents_and_fields) it is fairly classical to use a different format when you want to use a date as unique Id, like for example the following format `YYYYMMDD`. So you could use `20191209` instead of `Dec 9, 2019`.

---

However, having said that, it's also worth noting that it is not recommended to use **monotonically increasing document IDs** such as: `20191209`, `20191210`, `20191211`, because, as explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/best-practices#document_ids) "such sequential IDs can lead to [hotspots](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/best-practices#high_read_write_and_delete_rates_to_a_narrow_document_range) that impact latency."

So, if you plan to creates those `fitbit_sleep` documents "**at a very high rate**" and allocates them monotonically increasing IDs like `20191209`, `20191210`, `20191211` it will be better to adopt another strategy.

You could use the document IDs automatically allocated by Firestore by using the [`add()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference?authuser=1#add) method and add, to the newly created document itself, a field with the date value in format `YYYYMMDD`. You would then use a query to find a given document, as follows:

```
let userRef1 = firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(userId).collection("fitbit_sleep");

userRef1
  .where('date', '==', '20191209');
  .get()
  .then(querySnapshot => {  // Note: this a QuerySnapshot not a DocumentSnapshot
     console.log(querySnapshot.docs[0].data());
  })
```

---

**EDIT FOLLOWING THE EDIT OF YOUR QUESTION**

With you edit, it appears that you want to query for the most recent document in the collection `users/userId/fitbit_sleep`. For that you will need to **order** and **limit** the documents returned by your query, as explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data?authuser=1).

There are two cases:

**Case 1:** One of the timestamp fields in your documents (i.e. `dateAdded` or `endTime`) corresponds to the value you want to sort on (i.e. they correspond to the date represented by the document ID).

You can then order the query based on one of those fields and limit it to the last document, as follows:

```
let userRef1 = firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(userId).collection("fitbit_sleep");

userRef1
  .orderBy('endTime', 'desc')
  .limit(1)
  .get()
  .then(querySnapshot => {  // Note: this a QuerySnapshot not a DocumentSnapshot
     console.log(querySnapshot.docs[0].data());
  })
```

**Case 2** You cannot use on of those timestamp fields because they do not correspond to the date represented by the document ID. You will then need to add an extra field in your document, for example with a date value in format YYYYMMDD (if there is only one document per day), and sort on this field. So if you call this field `orderingDate`, you would adapt the above query as follows:

```
userRef1
  .orderBy('orderingDate', 'desc')
  .limit(1)
  .get()
  .then(querySnapshot => {  // Note: this a QuerySnapshot not a DocumentSnapshot
     console.log(querySnapshot.docs[0].data());
  })
```

Comment: thanks for the feedback once again! I tailored the querying to the case 2 and with a little tweak it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem already. I think it is impossible to get the document by query for every unique user? So I used the field `dataAdded` of the sub document `fitbit_sleep` of the logged in user instead to get() the latest date named document and all of the fields I need. I tailored it from Renaud's **Case 2 Answer**

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
 if(user){
  this.userId = user.uid;
 }
 let userRef1 = 
 firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(userId).collection("fitbit_sleep");
 return userRef1.get()
 .then(function(querySnapshot) {
  querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
   console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
   });
});
```

I changed it to this:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
 if(user){
  this.userId = user.uid;
 }
 let userRef1 = 
 firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(userId).collection("fitbit_sleep").orderBy("dateAdded", "desc").limit(1);
 return userRef1.get()
 .then(function(querySnapshot) {
  querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
   console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
   });
});
```

**And from the changed code if this applies to your projects, you should expect this as a result of the querying:**

[image]

Though I understand there are some concerns about the naming conventions of my documents. I totally agree with Renaud and Doug to at least replace the naming to unique ID or `uid` instead. But majority of the functionality especially with database manipulation is coming from the mobile application of our thesis project. I appreciate the feedback and I'll try to convince the mobile developer to follow conventions!